# Получение переменной 1 из строки с переменной 2 | phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Есть два параметра в базе данных: `userName` и `password`. Нужно получить `password`, используя переменную `userName`. Выглядеть это должно как-то так:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` where `password`
```

Находится в той же строке, где и `$user`.

Comment: Когда вы написали where users.username=$username,то будет отфильтрована вся строка

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
$query = "SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `userName`='$user'";
```

Comment: А твой код переменную $user  не будет воспринимать как сроку?

Comment: @ДмитрийАнисько, нет не будет.